# Jon Skeet was awarded the casting badge. Twice

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-badges

Is it supposed to be possible to get the new bronze tag badges multiple times? Or is that just because he's Jon Skeet?

https://stackoverflow.com/badges/509/casting

Comment: One for upcasts and one for downcasts? I wonder if I've got any other duplicates...

Comment: They felt bad for him because he's falling behind the rest of us in badge count

Comment: will fix tomorrow. a concurrency bug

Comment: I got a few dups too; I was pretty sure @waffles would be on the case already ;p

Comment: by tomorrow, I mean fixed now :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Jon Skeet violates the third normal form.

(fixed now)