# Tag badges page, too short to hold [• functional-programming] × 13

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, tag-badges

The width of the [Tag Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags) table is not wide enough to accomodate some very long tag names, for instance, [[ • functional-programming ]](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/387/functional-programming) and [[ • programming-languages ]](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/461/programming-languages). This causes the "× ??" indicator moved to the next line.

[image]

Comment: on my list of stuff for tomorrow :)

Comment: @waffles I've been [led to believe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63679/jon-skeet-was-awarded-the-casting-badge-twice) that means this will be fixed in a minute or so

Comment: :) I just committed a fix on dev, will be deployed with the next drop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is completed in dev, thanks for reporting it!