# Duplicated bronze tag-badges

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-badges

Some bronze tag badges are shown twice on the [badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags). They are **io** [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/729/io), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/730/io), **j2ee** [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/727/j2ee), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/728/j2ee), and **vb6** [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/710/vb6), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/711/vb6).

[image]

Comment: Also  `decorator`

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63679/jon-skeet-was-awarded-the-casting-badge-twice

Comment: @Hans: It is a different issue. The 2 badges awarded to Jon Skeet share the same badge ID, but the badges I listed above have different badge ID.

Comment: Also `active-directory` and `jquery-plugins`

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it, was part of a concurrency issue, thanks for letting me know