# Why is meta unprofessional?

Tags: discussion, meta

Since [my first post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212164/does-stack-overflow-fix-bugs-or-problems-reported-on-meta) I noticed that the meta site of Stack Exchange is very unprofessional. See first comment on same post, when I find that comment on my post I took it in a more professional way but they were making it a joke. Again I see upvotes on that joke. So it way of approaching any question on meta site?

Let's take another example: I find this one question that is one of the most popular on meta:
[Jon Skeet Facts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts).

Yes I find this question very interesting but aren't you people making jokes about [Mr. Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)?
I found upvotes on comment "Who the hell is Jon Skeet?". What is this?
Same with the tag https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/jon-skeet/info . How could you people make a tag of any person on this site?

Is there is any other approach which Meta follows rather than other sites on Stack?

Comment: Whoa, whoa, **whoa**.  The first comment on the first link was a tongue-in-cheek joke.  The second point is moot since ***Jon Skeet himself*** answered the question.  There's some thing that can be had in good fun, but by and large, Stack Exchange community members are professional.  Oh, and to your point about the tag? ...Okay, you have a point there.

Comment: This place has its own culture and humour. Just because it isn't always easy to immediately understand  doesn't necessarily mean it's in any way  "unprofessional".

Comment: @Makoto I find most of tongue-in-cheek joke here only. Why?

Comment: You do realize that the Jon Skeet Facts question was created in *2008* back when the site was just beginning, and is currently locked up tight for historical significance?

Comment: @Ankush why not?

Comment: @Pëkka So why dont u provide different guide line for this?

Comment: There's some humor and culture here, yes.  I won't deny that there are some times when a comment like that is well timed and well placed, and it *might* come across as unprofessional.  However, I assure you that Meta comes across as professional.

Comment: Professionals can have a little fun, too.

Comment: Yes, there is little guidance on how Meta is different. But that's part of how it's different. :) just hang back, be open about things and rest assured that while the culture here is... special, people are generally very nice and very serious about the quality of their greater communities.

Comment: Ok, got it. Sorry for `unprofessional` word. Thanks every one who clear my `meta` concept :)

Comment: No problem. Re Jon Skeet, as was already said, he is perfectly okay with people making jokes about him, and they are meant in no way to be hurtful or demeaning. The "who the hell is Jon Skeet" comment was a joke because of course, everyone knows who Jon Skeet is....  The same goes for the silly tag, which is more or less a joke as well. Most of the conversation here is, as you will note, serious, though, and it's generally much more serious than when the place started.

Comment: Comments on your first post are definitely too funny too handle ! :'D I'm glad having read it!

Comment: Well, meta has also off-topic close votes and the problematic questions can be closed. Instead of pointing out the whole meta is unprofessional you should link the problematic question and ask if it belongs here.

Comment: @ŁukaszL. Its countless. If you do that then meta will close :)

Comment: @ankitaalung Right, unless someone told me that comment was joke I never came to know about that comment was joke!

Comment: +1 to the question because I personally think meta should have more moderation than it currently does. Also, it is not unusual that "experienced" people jump on newcomers, and all what can be seen is upvotes all around except the newbie establishing an excluding feeling rather than inclusion.

Comment: After researching meta site I found few guidelines on one of [blog from Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/02/listen-to-your-community-but-dont-let-them-tell-you-what-to-do.html)

Comment: FWIW, there's no longer a [meta-tag:jon-skeet] tag.

Comment: @animuson Sorry, I didn't meant that, Jon Skeet tag is one of my favourite tag :).Please revert it back.

Comment: @Ankush: It is not a useful tag. Most of the times it gets used don't have anything to do with Jon Skeet himself, but just some report that happens to mention him. The whole three questions that used it properly have been merged into [meta-tag:fun].

Comment: @animuson did Jon Skeet confirm the murder of his precious tag? :D

Comment: Actually, there was some effects [only](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63679/225745) or [best](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99502/225745) visible on Jon Skeet account, due to his enormous rep and badge number, so tagging a bugreport with him made sense. Maybe not particularly useful, true, but not harmful and certainly shows respect.

Comment: @Mołot Certainly, we developer also respect Jon Steet(sorry we love him), he teach me lot of things in programming development.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because meta is, in and of itself, a rather undisciplined proposition. It is in fact the antithesis of the high signal to noise environment that we strive to create on our main sites. That's precisely [why we didn't have meta](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/cmon-get-meta/) for quite a while.

It's quite polarizing, if you think about it - going from no discussion and no chit-chat to *all* discussion and all chit-chat. Then consider how voting is completely different on meta sites. We basically turn our engine on its head.

When participating in a community entails frequent journeys between these strangely parallel universes, a little fun and humor helps human beings take it all in stride. Tongues go into cheeks, while unicorns and one-armed dragons make much more frequent cameo appearances. I'll admit that initially we went a little overboard with shenanigans, but we've come around to a sort of norm where we *get stuff done*, while still taking advantage of being able to enjoy the company of one another just a *little* more than we otherwise could.

We're building cites on meta sites, collectively, and doing a pretty good job of it. To that extent, we're quite professional, in that we tend to consistently produce awesome things.

Since a *little* fun now and then doesn't really detract from that goal, we're more than happy to have a helping or two on occasion. This is particularly noticeable during the holidays when even employees loosen up a bit and [reward people for simply enjoying the culture they created](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213769/work-is-hard-lets-color-the-walls).

Think of Meta like our cafeteria, where the *occasional* food fight is generally tolerated, provided that everyone is having a good time and getting *something* constructive done in the process.

Comment: There's simply no fun in writing code if you cannot throw food at others at the same time. :-)

Comment: @Jamal Oh, well, that explains all of the spaghetti code on Code Review then! Thanks, I'd been wondering about that.

Comment: *And* we know how to clean it all up. ;-) And the moderators just make sure there's no bloodshed...

Comment: Wait. That .... wasn't .. _sauce_? My God, what are you people _doing_ over there?

Comment: It's a Code Review thing.  You wouldn't understand.

Comment: @TinyTim You almost killed me with that spaghetti code joke.

Comment: @Some we also have [toast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html). Hungry? ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thank you, but i will get some [pike](http://pike.lysator.liu.se/) instead.